# Join entre duas tabelas selecionando todos os registros de um lado, mas com algumas regras de filtragem (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenho 3 tabelas que se relacionam entre si.

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde preciso retornar todos os registros de "EMISSORAS"

Porém é necessário filtrar essa consulta para me retornar o campo valor quando o id do produto for igual "4", mas se emissora não tiver registro cadastrado na tabela "TABELAS" ou se tiver outro produto diferente do id 4, que seja retornado essa emissora, mas com valores NULL.

O problema é que se a emissora tiver outro registro em "TABELAS" e não tiver cadastrado um registro com produtos_id = 4 ele não será retornado a mim visto que a claudusa "WHERE produtos_id = 4 OR produtos_id IS NULL"

```
--Tabela:
id
valor
produtos_id
emissoras_id
historico

--Produto:
id
produto
descricao
tipo
status

--Emissoras:
id
razao
nome_fantasia
[...]
```

Exemplo de dados:

```
--Produtos:
1, Spot 30, Spot 30 segundos, spot, 1
2, Spot 15, Spot 15 segundos, spot, 1
3, Spot 5, Spot 5 segundos, spot, 1
4, Testemunhal, Texto ao vivo, testemunhal, 1
5, Outro produto, Outro produto qualquer, outro, 1

--Tabelas:
1, 30.50, 4, 2
2, 25.50, 2, 3
3, 45.50, 3, 3
4, 43.50, 2, 3

--Emissoras:
1, Emissora 1, Emissora 1
2, Emissora 2, Emissora 2
3, Emissora 3, Emissora 3
4, Emissora 4, Emissora 4
5, Emissora 5, Emissora 5
```

Dados que preciso retornados:
Emissoras.razao, tabelas.valor, tabelas.id, tabelas.produtos_id (ou produtos.id), produtos.produto

O resultado esperado é:

```
Emissora 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
Emissora 2, 30.50, 1, 4, Testemunhal
Emissora 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
Emissora 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
Emissora 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Como contorno isso ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Publique a estrutura das tabelas se possível. Se quer ou não se quer os id <> 4 !? Para não existentes um OUTER JOIN parece resolver.

Comment: A estrutura da tabela está na imagem acima. (foi um print tirado do proprio banco)
No caso eu quero retornar todos que são igual a 4, mas aqueles que não são tem que vir com mas o campo "valor" deve vir sem nada ou igual a 0

Comment: A estrutura facilita a criação do esquema num sqlfiddle , pesquise por OUTER JOIN e teste (produto.id = 4 or produto.id is null)

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Vejam se agora está mais clara e detalhada.

Answer (score 0):

parar substituir os campos que estão nulo no select, você pode utilizar a estrutura ISNULL(coluna, 0).

SELECT
ISNULL(coluna, 0)
FROM Tabela

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).